# why is coherence of subspace always at least 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The common definition of coherence in the matrix recovery literature is as follows. Let $U$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of dimension $r$ and let $P_U$ be the orthogonal projection onto $U$. Define the coherence of $U$ as
$$
  \mu(U) = \frac{n}{r} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \lVert P_U e_i \rVert^2
$$
where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.

The claim is that $\mu(U) \geq 1$ for any subspace $U$. I know how to prove this when we restrict ourselves to $U$ of rank 1:
$$
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{n} \mu(U) &\geq \inf_{u:u^Tu=1} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \lVert uu^T e_i \rVert^2 \\
&= \inf_{u:u^Tu=1} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}  (u^T e_i)^2 \\
&= \inf_{u:u^Tu=1} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}  (u_i)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}
$$
where the last equality holds since the minimum is obtained when all entries of $u$ are the same (and we need the norm to be 1). My attempt to generalize this proof is as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{r}{n} \mu(U) &\geq \inf_{U\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times r} : U^T U=I} \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \lVert UU^T e_i \rVert^2 \\
&= \inf_{U\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times r} : U^T U=I} \max_{1\leq i \leq n} e_i^T UU^T e_i \\
&= \inf_{U\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times r} : U^T U=I} \max_{1\leq i \leq n} (UU^T)_{ii}
\end{align*}
$$
I'm stuck on how to complete this proof-- how do we show the minimizing $U$ is one where each diagonal element is $\frac{r}{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the $\|Pe_i\|^2=e_r^TPe_r$. You have that the trace of $P$ is $r$, so 
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n e_i^T Pe_i = r.
$$
Thus the mean of the diagoanl entries of $P$ is $n/r$, and therefore the maximum is at least this large.